# Designing a (recursive) log object for an event logging system

Tags: c++, oop, logging, graphing

I'm designing a system that is supposed to store events. Each event has three basic properties:
1. timestamp (64bit)
2. key (what it is).
3. value (the actual value for the event).

Event keys are usually strings, event values are almost always numbers.

Simple so far, but, here it gets a bit muddy. The event system is supposed to allow drilldown to a very high level. What this means is best illustrated with an example:

NB: Leaving out timestamp for brevity.

```
key: hits // might be per hour, might be in the last second, the key is application specific, its up to the user to figure out how often his application reports this event to us.
value: 12000
 // and here the drilldown starts.
 key: US
 value: 5000
  key: State1
   value: 2000
    key: City1
    value: 500
 key: UK
 value: 5000
  key: StateN
   value: 20
 // to an arbitrary level.
```

So, as you can see above, the value actually turns into a tree.
One might say, well, why not store each k/v independently and maintain a "parent key", this would be inefficient due to increasing write (and eventually, when events are looked up, read load). it would be much more efficient to write them out in one operation, and read back the entire object at one go.

I'm wondering how best to design this. The objects are essentially a C++ class (although, for inter-operability, it's actually a serialization framework ala protocol buffers/thrift).

The event system is application agnostic, but I want a nice API to provide the clients that's intuitive.

Have you designed something like this before? Thoughts? What do you think is the best way to go about it?

Thank you in advance.

P.S: A few million events are expected per day, and we'll be building graphs based off the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you extend the log file definition to provide a "group" or "package" type log tag?

For example :

> group:US  key:
> State1
> value: 7000
> key: State2
> value: 65191
>
> group:UK ...

That way you could solve parsing per each group...if that's what you are looking for...

Comment: There is technically no difference between State1 and US, though (other than heirarchically), so, in that case, we'd haveto provide a group for every single depth, which makes it annoying, and in some cases, non-sensical.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind is also give your entries a fourth property: parent log entry id. With a ORM like ActiveRecord you can then form a natural tree. For example:

```
class LogEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :parent_log_entry
    has_many :log_entries
end
```

(That's surely not correct as it stands, but you'll get the idea).

There are various implementations of the ActiveRecord scheme in various languages, so that'd be pretty language (and DB) agnostic.

Comment: Wouldn't this suffer from the write performance/read performance problems I mentioned with the parent ID implementation in the question?

Comment: I don't see how you would have "additional writes"... I mean, you could create a nested format for one line, like `['key1':'value1' [ 'subkey1':'subvalue1', 'subkey2':'subvalue2']]` which would be a little bit shorter, but only by a few bytes. My proposal would be natural and easy to implement if you're using a DB as log storage but of course harder if you're using a file based approach.